# "Давайте говорить как петербуржцы"

Tags: общие-вопросы

В Санкт-Петербурге проводится акция Санкт-Петербургского государственного университета при поддержке губернатора "Давайте говорить как петербуржцы". По городу развешаны плакаты, в которых приведены типичные ошибки современной речи, даются рекомендации по правильному употреблению слов, расстановке ударений и т. п.

Нет сомнений, акция очень полезная. Но как вам лозунг? По-моему, несколько неоднозначен. А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

---

***Update***

Говоря о неоднозначности лозунга, я имела в виду ощущаемый в нем оттенок снобизма. Говорить по-русски правильно - это хорошо. Но почему говорить как петербуржцы лучше, чем говорить как псковичи, вологжане или читинцы?

Answer (score 3):

Я, когда прочитала заголовок (он же название акции), почему-то подумала о призыве употреблять  слова, характерные для Санкт-Петербурга. Например, кура, парадная и т. п. Из вашего пояснения понятно, что речь о другом. :)

Сама идея хорошая, мне нравится. Хоть что-то полезное будет мелькать перед глазами вместо надоедливой рекламы. Одни заинтересуются, другие запомнят информацию  невольно, что тоже неплохо. 
  Название не самое подходящее, немного с вызовом что ли. Но лучше так, чем совсем ничего.

Comment: + многа!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ну да. Есть шаверму из куры и выходить из парадного на поребрик. 
Хотя лично я подумал прежде всего о фонетических особенностях. Не буду углублять, любой поисковик даст их без всяких проблем.

Подумал, а если попросить говорить "как москвичи" - это как воспримут?
С грустью вынужден констатировать, что в массе это воспримут не иначе как предложение говорить с кавказско-среднеазиатским акцентом.(((

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем говорить по-петербуржски, давайте уберём из речи мат по-русски!

Comment: Марк, насчет академии , - не знаю. Я не живу в России.

Answer (score -1):

Действительно, полезные рекомендации есть. Но вот с курами, топлеcсом, поребриком — дела плохи.

Comment: @Серж, в интернете много чего есть. Не всему надо верить. Судя по Вашей ссылке на сайт smixer.ru, Вы не отличаете фейки от настоящих новостей, да еще и популяризируете подобную чушь.

Comment: Ссылок я не давал!Ну и утверждать , что это правда, я тоже не утверждал. Поэтому и задал вопрос здесь, чтоб узнать, правда это или нет.

Comment: а кто под Вашим ником давал ссылку в вопросе про троллинг грамматика?

Comment: Какую еще ссылку? Вы, наверное, что-то путаете. Я сейчас посмотрю. Не помню, чтобы давал ссылок.

Comment: А, нашел. А какое отношение имеет эта ссылка к нашей сегодняшней теме? К тому же, то, что указано в ссылке, - правда. Об этом даже говорил в своем интервью один из современных лингвистов( именно в интервью впервые я прочитал об этом).  Кто именно, - не помню точно. По-моему , Максим Кронгауз( не уверен).

Comment: Отношение прямое: тот сайт, как и эта картинка - фейки. Похоже, не Вы один попались на эту удочку.

Comment: Насчет картинки не берусь утверждать, но насчет новости , опубликованной на том сайте , повторяюсь,- это не фейк. Т.к. прежде , чем зайти на этот сайт, я читал об этом в интервью лингвиста.

Comment: @Серж, вы серьёзно считаете, что в России есть академия "**Бодуна**-де-Куртене", филолог для плаката будет позировать со стопариком, а Горький писать о тех кто мочится мимо унитаза, это уж ни говоря об названиях книг Натальи Романовой?